Alpine.js x-init not setting value
Alpine.js x-init does not set the expected value. It shows the console.log value twice. Firstly it shows the correct value then immediately it shows null. Why does it render twice?
<ul
    x-data="{ opened: null, loadOpened() {               
            const submenus = document.querySelectorAll('.submenu-link');
            submenus.forEach(submenu => {
                const currentUrl = window.location.href;
                const href = submenu.getAttribute('href');
                const cleanHref = href.replace(/^\.\.\//, '');

                if (currentUrl.includes(cleanHref)) {
                    const submen uName =  submenu.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-submenu');
                    this.opened = submenuName;
                    console.log(this.opened, submenuName);
                }
            });                
        
    }}"
    x-init="loadOpened()"
    class="flex flex-col gap-2 bb-dashed-n30 xl:mb-5 xl:pb-5 m-text font-medium"
>

I am trying to fix this but it's not working. I need to set submenuName on opened state, but it is set to null

From your code I can see only a typo in const submen uName =  submenu.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-submenu'); Can you also post an example for elements with class submenu-link? (They are  tags I suppose)
